# Unexpected Strings sum

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone, output

i have the current code:

```
  http_server.Text = "5.79.16.127‏‏‏";

  http_port.Text = "8180";

  http_dimensione.Text = "3000000";

  http_ripetizioni.Text = "1";

  String static_link = "/autotestsuite/test/download.test?size=";

  String dimensione = http_dimensione.Text;  

  String ripetizioni = http_ripetizioni.Text;

  ripetizioni_number = Convert.ToInt32(ripetizioni);

  String durata = http_durata.Text;

  String server = http_server.Text;

  String port = http_port.Text;

  url = "http://" + server +":"+ port + static_link + dimensione;

  Debug.WriteLine("url "+url);
```

now what do you expect to see in debug output?
i cant really uderstand because i get this:

```
 I GET THIS OUTPUT
 url http://5.79.16.127‏‏‏:8180/autotestsuite/test/download.test?size=3000000
```

i had expected to get this output:

```
 I EXPECT THIS OUTPUT
 url http://5.79.16.127:8180/autotestsuite/test/download.test?size=3000000
```

Comment: Are you sure? Did you debug your code? What do you see in your debugger? Could be these values coming from somewhere else? Because your code (as far as I see) looks fine.

Comment: unrelated, but you should really create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding instead of `Convert.ToInt32` and stuff like that.

Comment: yea im sure , debugger output just print that , i really cant understand why.

Comment: the Convert.ToInt32 dont interest the problem that variable its not in the string concatenation

Comment: i try to set the variable http_server.Text = "5.79.16.127‏‏‏" to http_server.Text = "5.79.16.127‏‏‏:" and to remove ":" from variable url.... but i still getting same output

Comment: Try adding the colon to http_port.Text = ":8080"

Comment: i tryed now i change  http_port.Text = "8180" to  http_port.Text = ":8180" and change url = "http://" + server + port + static_link + dimensione; i still getting http://5.79.16.127‏‏‏:8180/autotestsuite/test/download.test?size=3000000

Comment: Is the url just a string? how is it initialized?

Comment: String url; as class variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this :

```
String server_copied = "5.79.16.127‏‏‏";
foreach(var a in server_copied .ToCharArray())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} U+{1:x4} {2}", a, (int)a, (int)a);
}

String server_typed = "5.79.16.127";
foreach(var a in server_typed.ToCharArray())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} U+{1:x4} {2}", a, (int)a, (int)a);
}
```

All text after `server_copied` to semicolon is copy-pasted from snippet in this question. And the same part after `server_typed` are manually typed.

I can see 3 unprintable characters after `7 U+0037 55` from `server_copied .ToCharArray()`. Without those characters the string will be concatenated as you expect (`//5.79.16.127:8180` instead of `//5.79.16.1278180:`).

Code snippet to print character along with it's ASCII number is from [http://geekswithblogs.net](http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/05/25/79561.aspx)

Comment: +1 nice catch, if you put the caret between the 7 and " it will eat several left-arrow keys

Comment: ok i understand the problem , i think there is some strange char that my pc dont load, dont know why , but the same code written in another machine work fine if i copy paste it.